# Unable to verify_certificates for login authentication using Safenet eToken 5110 and self-signed cert

Tags: rhel7, two-factor-authentication, safenet, e-token

I'm trying to configure the SafeNet eToken 5110 for 2FA login authentication on RHEL7.9.

- Operating System: RHEL Workstation 7.9
- SafeNet Authentication Client 10.7.77.0

My system is air-gapped, and thus will be using a self-signed X509 certificate for local authentication.

However, after loading my certs and configuring my system accordingly, I am able to view my loaded cert on the token via the SafeNet Authentication Client, but pkcs11 does not seem to be able to find/verify my cert when used to login.

Any advice on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated!

I've included my CA cert in `/etc/pam_pkcs11/cacerts` as well as in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors`

I've updated the cn_map in /etc/pamkcs11/cn_map to map my user (admin) to the common name of my cert (admin) as follows:
cn_map

```
admin -> admin
```

Added my module and configured to use CN mapper
pam_pkcs11.conf

```
#
# Configuration file for pam_pkcs11 module
#
# Version 0.4
# Author: Juan Antonio Martinez <jonsito@teleline.es>
#
pam_pkcs11  {
    # Allow empty passwords
    nullok = true;

    # Enable debugging support.
    debug = true;

    # If the smart card is inserted, only use it
    card_only = true;

    # Do not prompt the user for the passwords but take them from the
    # PAM_ items instead.
    use_first_pass = false;

    # Do not prompt the user for the passwords unless PAM_(OLD)AUTHTOK
    # is unset.
    try_first_pass = false;

    # Like try_first_pass, but fail if the new PAM_AUTHTOK has not been
    # previously set (intended for stacking password modules only).
    use_authtok = false;

    # Filename of the PKCS #11 module. The default value is "default"
    use_pkcs11_module = eToken;

    screen_savers = "gnome-screensaver", xscreensaver, kscreensaver;
    
    pkcs11_module eToken {
        #module = /usr/lib64/libIDPrimePKCS11.so;
        module = /usr/lib64/libeTPkcs11.so;
        description = "eToken";
        slot_num = 0;
        support_threads = true;
        ca_dir = /etc/pam_pkcs11/cacerts;
        nss_dir = /etc/pki/nssdb;
        cert_policy = none;
    }

    # Which mappers ( Cert to login ) to use?
    # you can use several mappers:
    #
    # subject - Cert Subject to login file based mapper
    # pwent   - CN to getpwent() login or gecos fields mapper
    # ldap    - LDAP mapper
    # opensc  - Search certificate in ${HOME}/.eid/authorized_certificates
    # openssh - Search certificate public key in ${HOME}/.ssh/authorized_keys
    # mail    - Compare email fields from certificate
    # ms      - Use Microsoft Universal Principal Name extension
    # krb     - Compare againts Kerberos Principal Name
    # cn      - Compare Common Name (CN)
    # uid     - Compare Unique Identifier
    # digest  - Certificate digest to login (mapfile based) mapper
    # generic - User defined certificate contents mapped
    # null    - blind access/deny mapper
    #
    # You can select a comma-separated mapper list.
    # If used null mapper should be the last in the list :-)
    # Also you should select at least one mapper, otherwise
    # certificate will not match :-)
    use_mappers = cn;

    # When no absolute path or module info is provided, use this
    # value as module search path
    # TODO:
    # This is not still functional: use absolute pathnames or LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
    mapper_search_path = "/usr/$LIB/pam_pkcs11";


    # Assume common name (CN) to be the login
    mapper cn {
        debug = false;
        module = internal;
        # module = /usr/$LIB/pam_pkcs11/cn_mapper.so;
        ignorecase = false;
        mapfile = "file:///etc/pam_pkcs11/cn_map";
    }
}
```

I've also added my module to the NSS database

```
# modutil -dbdir /etc/pki/nssdb/ -list

Listing of PKCS #11 Modules
-----------------------------------------------------------
  1. NSS Internal PKCS #11 Module
       uri: pkcs11:library-manufacturer=Mozilla%20Foundation;library-description=NSS%20Internal%20Crypto%20Services;library-version=3.44
     slots: 2 slots attached
    status: loaded

     slot: NSS Internal Cryptographic Services
    token: NSS Generic Crypto Services
      uri: pkcs11:token=NSS%20Generic%20Crypto%20Services;manufacturer=Mozilla%20Foundation;serial=0000000000000000;model=NSS%203

     slot: NSS User Private Key and Certificate Services
    token: NSS Certificate DB
      uri: pkcs11:token=NSS%20Certificate%20DB;manufacturer=Mozilla%20Foundation;serial=0000000000000000;model=NSS%203

  2. CoolKey PKCS #11 Module
    library name: libcoolkeypk11.so
       uri: pkcs11:library-manufacturer=Mozilla%20Foundation;library-description=CoolKey%20PKCS%20%2311%20Module%20%20%20%20%20;library-version=1.0
     slots: 1 slot attached
    status: loaded

     slot: VMware Virtual USB CCID 00 00
    token: 
      uri: pkcs11:

  3. SafeNet eToken
    library name: /usr/lib64/libeTPkcs11.so
       uri: pkcs11:library-manufacturer=SafeNet,%20Inc.;library-description=SafeNet%20eToken%20PKCS%2311;library-version=10.7
     slots: 8 slots attached
    status: loaded

     slot: VMware Virtual USB CCID 00 00
    token: SafeNet Token
      uri: pkcs11:token=SafeNet%20Token;manufacturer=SafeNet,%20Inc.;serial=02956a8d;model=eToken

     slot: 
    token: 
      uri: pkcs11:

     slot: 
    token: 
      uri: pkcs11:

     slot: 
    token: 
      uri: pkcs11:

     slot: 
    token: 
      uri: pkcs11:

     slot: 
    token: 
      uri: pkcs11:

     slot: 
    token: 
      uri: pkcs11:

     slot: 
    token: 
      uri: pkcs11:
```

Terminal Output

```
pkcs11_inspect debug
DEBUG:pam_config.c:238: Using config file /etc/pam_pkcs11/pam_pkcs11.conf
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:182: Initializing NSS ...
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:192: Initializing NSS ... database=/etc/pki/nssdb
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:212: ...  NSS Complete
DEBUG:pkcs11_inspect.c:69: loading pkcs #11 module...
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:237: Looking up module in list
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:240: modList = 0x79aae0 next = 0x7a9760

DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:241: dllName= <null> 

DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:240: modList = 0x7a9760 next = 0x7d5b80

DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:241: dllName= libcoolkeypk11.so 

DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:240: modList = 0x7d5b80 next = 0x0

DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:241: dllName= libeTPkcs11.so 

DEBUG:pkcs11_inspect.c:78: initialising pkcs #11 module...
PIN for token: 
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:48: PIN = [PASSWORD]
DEBUG:pkcs11_lib.c:768: no certs found found
ERROR:pkcs11_inspect.c:120: get_certificates() failed:
```

I am expecting that after keying in the correct PIN for the configured token, the cert should be verified and I am able to login.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm in a similar situation now but on linux mint, also using safenet authentication client. I get as far as keying in the pin but then it seems like no cert is sent. I have also added the CA certs to the nssdb and verified that they're there.